# apt-get install doesn't install latest version of Owncloud Client

Tags: apt, raspbian

I'm trying to install the latest version of the Owncloud Client (`owncloud-client`) on a raspberry Pi running Raspbian Linux.

When I just enter `sudo apt-get install owncloud-client`, I get version 1.2 of the client.
So I added the Owncloud repository from the [official download page](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv%3aownCloud%3adesktop&package=owncloud-client) and ran all the commands from the Debian-section as root.

But when I try to install `owncloud-client` now, i still get the version 1.2 (and not the latest Version, which is 1.6.1

Do I need apt-pinning for this or is there a simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you run this command `apt-cache search owncloud-client` and `apt-cache policy owncloud-client` and send the output???

Comment: Did you remember to run `apt-get update` to update the db?

Comment: That repository you link to doesn't contain the package for ARM, just amd64 and i386.

Comment: Thanks @Leiaz, your answer was very helpful! If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it so that you get rep for it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv%3aownCloud%3adesktop&package=owncloud-client) given on the official download page doesn't contain any package for ARM, just amd64 and i386. So `apt` can't find a package there that would work on the Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 1):

to install the latest version you have to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
```

And the latest available in all your repositories will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a repository with client 2.3.2 and a tutorial to build the client. See https://wiki.sgripon.net/doku.php/building_owncloud_client_for_raspberry_pi.